# Same ACF Relationship field for multiple Post Options sub-pages?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, options, add-submenu-page

How can I ensure that the data saved by an Advanced Custom Fields [Relationship](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) field, when on an Options page for a Post type, is separate?

Detail below:

I have an ACF field group, “Features”, containing a Relationship field.

It is intended to allow me to pre-set some featured posts for a couple of custom post types – “Reports” and “Articles”.

For those post types, in the same code that registers each post type, I have created an Options sub-page like this…

```
// Support showcase Features for this post type, via ACF

if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    // add sub page
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Articles Features',
        'menu_title'    => 'Articles Features',
    'menu_slug'   => 'articles-features',
    'capability'  => 'edit_posts',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=article',
    'position'    => false,
    'icon_url'    => false
    ));

}
```

The same goes for “Reports”.

And then I apply the “Features” field group to both Options sub-pages – “Articles Features” and “Reports Features”.

The problem is… the data is the same.
That is, the six Relationship posts set for “Reports Features” also show up in the Options sub-page for “Articles Features”. Changing one Relationship field overwrites the other.

How can I ensure that these two things are separate, so that I can save the features distinctly per post type, without recreating the field group?

Answer (score 0):

The method to use is...

In the `acf_add_options_sub_page` declaration, add `'post_id' => 'article'` as a parameter. ([post_id](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/))

This is how the field data, as entered on the Options page corresponding to my post type, will be saved.

On the display end, display using `$featured_posts = get_field('featured_posts', 'article');`

'article' and 'report' are both used.

In my case, at the display end, I use `$queried_object->name` to dynamically infer either 'article' or 'report' post types.

Credit [hube2](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/different-values-for-same-field-groups-on-different-options-pages/#post-85935)